# merging two tables with same column in meaning into one

Tags: sql

I've got tables like this:

```
Table Articles
---------------
AID(PK)   Name   PublisherID   Words


Table Books
---------------
BID(PK)   Title  PublisherID   Date
```

I want to merge them like:

```
Table Total
---------------
Title   PublisherID
```

In this new table, **Name** in Table.Articles will belong to **Title** column,
because.. Articles.**Name** and Books.**Title** mean the same thing :)

Any answers will be very appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select title, publisherid from books
union all
select name, publisherid from articles
```

Comment: In oracle, "CREATE TABLE as (the David Aldridge query)" to create the table with the apropiate structure and copy all the data.

Comment: @wooohoh it is actually "union all". It is worth nothing that "union all" will list all the entries from your tables including duplicates. Using just "union" will eliminate duplicates - each entry will be listed only once. You need to decide which behaviour is desirable in your scenario

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you are looking for the result of this:

```
select name, publisherId
from TableArticles
union 
select title, publisherId
from TableBooks
```

Comment: Problem about this query is, if there are same name/title, they will be merged. But thanks for a reply anyway!!!